# Attempting to use table view in ios, getting error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view in my iOS tabbed application, but I can't run the app, I get this error at runtime:

```
3/23/12 10:15:23.119 PM CodeCompanion: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "2-view-16" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
 *** First throw call stack:
(0x13bd052 0x154ed0a 0x1365a78 0x13659e9 0x2436ae 0xda5cb 0xf5b89 0xf59bd 0xf3f8a 0xf3e2f 0xf1ffb 0xf285a 0xdbfbf 0xdc21b 0xdd0f1 0x4bfec 0x51572 0x4b72b 0x3abc2 0x3ace2 0x3aea8 0x41d9a 0x12be6 0x138a6 0x22743 0x231f8 0x16aa9 0x12a7fa9 0x13911c5 0x12f6022 0x12f490a 0x12f3db4 0x12f3ccb 0x132a7 0x14a9b 0x2888 0x27e5)
```

My View Controller header file is below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class LanguageTableViewCell;

@interface LanguagesViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSArray *languages;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *languages;

@end
```

and my implementation file is:

```
#import "LanguagesViewController.h"
#import "LanguageTableViewCell.h"

@implementation LanguagesViewController

@synthesize languages;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"getting cell for row at index path: %i", [indexPath row]);
    LanguageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"languageBase"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[LanguageTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                reuseIdentifier:@"languageBase"];
    }
    [cell setName:[languages objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"rows in section: %i is: %i", section, [languages count]);
    return [languages count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"getting number of sections (1)");
    return 1;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"view loaded, setting array");
    languages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Java", nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

I'm pretty new to xcode and objective-c, so mention anything that could have gone wrong. I have set the ViewController of the table view to my above class, and I am not getting any errors or warnings in xcode. The table view is one of those dynamic ones that use prototype cells. If I need to post the class of the cell, I will.

Comment: change the superclass from UITableViewController to UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your error message you're using a nib file, "2-view-16", to layout your view but it doesn't contain a UITableView (or it isn't hooked up).

The LanguagesViewController inherits from UITableViewController which is looking for a UITableView to control which doesn't exist.

If you're using a nib to setup the view, you'll need to add a UITableView to the nib and set it to be the tableView of your LanguagesViewController.

Comment: I'm using storyboards. Sorry for my ignorance, but that's different, right?

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm not familiar with Storyboards so I won't be able to help.

Comment: @sampage:  tableView is not an exposed outlet of UITableViewController (stupidly enough), he must create his own, and then set it not only as the tableView, but as the view.

Comment: Did not work for me, I added my own table view to the screen and then tried to connect it to UITableViewController with the following code in `loadView`: `self.tableView = self.foldersTableView; self.view = self.foldersTableView; [super loadView];`. Also overrode `- (UITableView *)tableView` to return my own instance, but it's not even called. Still the same error.